# Minizinc model fails with "MiniZinc: internal error: Error: solver backend cannot handle constraint: float_div"

Tags: minizinc

I'm just a beginner looking to see if I can use minizinc in my daily routine. The very first model I'm trying to make is [here](https://github.com/eosfor/tools/blob/graphs-n-minizinc-demo/demo/graphs-n-minizinc-demo/vmCostsCalculation.mzn) and the data file is [here](https://github.com/eosfor/tools/blob/graphs-n-minizinc-demo/demo/graphs-n-minizinc-demo/vmData.dzn)

Basically, what I'm trying to do is this. On one hand, I have a set of Virtual Machines with some attributes, like a number of cores, RAM, etc. On another hand, I have a set of VMs I pull from the cloud provider. Those also have similar properties and a price. What I'm trying to do is to match them and then find an optimal balance between the size of the corresponding VM in the cloud and its price.

For example, if I have a VM with 2 Cores and 8 GB of RAM. To match it I can potentially use a few kinds of VMs from the cloud provider which should have not less than 2 Cores and not less than 8 GB of RAM/ But for the set of such VMs I want to minimize the overall cost and at the same time try to maximize performance, which is measured in `ACUs` in terms of the cloud provider.

I wanted to use `var float: targetFunc = (0.9 * totalPrice) / (0.1 * totalACU);` as a target function, assuming that coefficients will help me to fine-tune the model towards price vs performance. But, perhaps, I'm doing it wrong.

I just copy and paste the code below, for simplicity.

```
enum existingVMs;
enum vmSizes;
enum vmDisks;

array[existingVMs] of int: vmCPU;
array[existingVMs] of int: vmRAM;
array[existingVMs] of int: vmDisk;
array[existingVMs] of int: vmCpuToRamRatio;


array[vmSizes] of int: vmSizeCPU;
array[vmSizes] of float: vmSizeRAM;
array[vmSizes] of int: vmSizePrice;
array[vmSizes] of int: vmSizeACU;
array[vmSizes] of int: vmSizeCpuToRamRatio;

array[vmDisks] of int: vmDiskSizes;
array[vmDisks] of float: vmDiskPrice;

array[existingVMs] of var vmSizes: selectedSize;
array[existingVMs] of var vmDisks: selectedDiskSize;


constraint forall(vm in existingVMs)(
    vmSizeACU[selectedSize[vm]] > 50
);

constraint forall(vm in existingVMs)(
    vmSizeRAM[selectedSize[vm]] >= vmRAM[vm]
);


constraint forall(vm in existingVMs)(
   vmSizeCPU[selectedSize[vm]] >=  vmCPU[vm] * 0.8
);

var int: totalPrice = sum(vm in existingVMs)(vmSizePrice[selectedSize[vm]]);
var int: totalACU = sum(vm in existingVMs)( vmSizeACU[selectedSize[vm]] );
var float: targetFunc = (0.9 * totalPrice) / (0.1 * totalACU);

solve maximize targetFunc;

output [ "\(totalPrice); \(totalACU)\n" ++ join("\n", ["\(vm), \(vmCPU[vm]), \(vmRAM[vm]), " ++ 
                                           "\(vmDisk[vm]), \(selectedSize[vm]), \(vmSizeCPU[selectedSize[vm]]), " ++ 
                                           "\(vmSizeRAM[selectedSize[vm]]), \(vmDiskSizes[selectedDiskSize[vm]]), " ++ 
                                           "\(vmSizePrice[selectedSize[vm]]), \(vmSizeACU[selectedSize[vm]])" | vm in  existingVMs]) ]
```

I run it as:

```
minizinc.exe  -i --solver coin-bc -s -a C:\Work\tools\demo\graphs-n-minizinc-demo\vmCostsCalculation.mzn C:\Work\tools\demo\graphs-n-minizinc-demo\vmData.dzn
```

And get the following in response

```
82 POSTs [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ], LINEQ [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,82, ], 82 / 82 vars, 82 cliques, 1 / 1 / 1 NSubIntv m/a/m, 252 / 252 / 252 SubIntvSize m/a/m, 82+0(0) clq eq_encoded  ... % Generated FlatZinc statistics:
%%%mzn-stat: paths=0
%%%mzn-stat: flatIntVars=21158
%%%mzn-stat: flatFloatVars=20831
%%%mzn-stat: flatIntConstraints=412
%%%mzn-stat: flatFloatConstraints=20831
%%%mzn-stat: method="maximize"
%%%mzn-stat: flatTime=4.09564
%%%mzn-stat-end

MiniZinc: internal error: Error: solver backend cannot handle constraint: float_div
```

I tried to use `gecode` but it is too slow, and never gets to the optimal solution.

Do I do something wrong and where? Maybe I need to set the target function differently, but I can't really understand what I should change and why it does not work this way.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason you get the error `solver backend cannot handle constraint: float_div` is that the CBC solver do not support non-linear constraints (such as the `div` constraint), only linear constraints.  There are some solvers that do support nonlinear float constraints, for example Gecode, JaCoP, OptiMathSAT, and Choco. 
 
It you add small data set to your question so we can be run the model, perhaps we might get a better tip to speed it up.

Comment: the dataset is on the link [here](https://github.com/eosfor/tools/blob/graphs-n-minizinc-demo/demo/graphs-n-minizinc-demo/vmData.dzn)

Comment: Do you have a smaller dataset?

Comment: Hello, @hakank

I've reduced the dataset and pushed files to the git repo. Actually the set of "source VMs" is the same. I reduced the "cloud provider" set.

when I try to `solve minimize totalPrice;` using the `coin-bc`, it returns almost immediately. The same one with `gecode` never ends. The last solution is far behind the one found by `coin-bc`

Inerestingly, when I do `solve minimize targetFunc;` where the `targetFunc` is `var float: targetFunc = (0.9 * totalPrice) / (0.1 * totalACU);` on the reduced dataset, the `coin-bc` does not fail and returns and answer. Gecode never ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the CBC solver throws the error `backend cannot handle constraint: float_div` is that this solver do not support non-linear constraints, such as the `div` constraint in the objective `targetFunc`. It only supports linear constraints.

There are some solvers that do support nonlinear float constraints, for example Gecode, JaCoP, OptiMathSAT, and Choco.

For speeding up the Gecode solver you can try to add search heuristics to the `solve` function, such as:

```
solve :: int_search(selectedDiskSize,first_fail,indomain_split) maximize targetFunc;
```

The search annotations are described here: https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/lib-annotations.html#search-annotations .

The reason I asked for a smaller data set is that in these cases one might try different heuristics, and then a smaller data set is much faster for getting a good selection.

Using float values in data and the model restricts the range of the FlatZinc solvers that can be used. There are quite a few more solvers that handle models with only integer variables and values.

So another approach might be to convert all the float values to integers (by multiplying by some constant, and adjust other values accordingly). Then all the other FlatZinc solvers can be used, e.g. Chuffed, OR-tools, PicatSAT, etc.

Comment: yeah, I realized that and converted floats to ints, it, I think, solved a problem. 

The next challenge, however, is "multi-objective optimization", as I need to minimize one parameter - cost, and maximize, say, "performance". @hakank. do you have any examples of such a model for gecode or cbc?

Comment: in regards to OptiMathSAT, I was not able to make it work with minizinc on a windows machine. the documentation they provide is very poor

Comment: @Eosfor The best way to do multi-objective optimization (in MiniZinc) is probably to do what you did in the original model: Creating a decision variable which is the sum of the two objectives (which have different weights according to importance).  Another approach is to first optimize for one parameter, add this as a constraint and then optimize for the other parameter. However, this cannot be done in plain MiniZinc, but requires some kind of wrapper, e.g. MiniZinc-Python: https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

Comment: @Eosfor And if you think my answer solves your problem, please accept is as a solution.

Comment: > Another approach is to first optimize for one parameter, add this as a constraint and then optimize for the other parameter

that is a great idea, thanks!